# Generate 2-Target WatchOS Template in XCode 14

Tags: xcode, watchos, xcode14

How do you generate a new watch app project in XCode 14 that corresponds to the only 2-target template.

In XCode 14, the default project template is a single / universal target application.

I'm not quite familiar with SwiftUI and how to develop for that template.  Is it possible to create a new project with the old template.